# Deploying a rails app to 1&1 Virtual Server L Windows first steps

Tags: windows-server-2008, ruby-on-rails, deployment, 1and1

Evening all,

I have a rails app that I need to deploy to a 1&1 Virtual Server L Windows.

My setup uses a MYSQL db, rails 3.2, ruby 1.9 and was built on a mac.

I have read numerous accounts of Linux style deployments, however do the same rules apply when using a windows server? This [article](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-on-windows-in-production/) mentions ftp'ing your app and then installing 3 other dependencies. Is this too good to be true?

I realise this is a fairly open ended question, but does anyone know the first few steps to getting this thing up and running or any helpful documents?

Thanks in Advance

Andy